# Eclipse RCP - DIsplay thread on Java

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have this function that should fire a notification window

```
public void PushNotif(String notifTitile,String notifText,int notifType) 
{
        Random r = new Random();
        int max = NotificationType.values().length;
        final String Title = notifTitile==null?"no Title":notifTitile;
        final String Text = notifText==null?"no Text":notifText;
        final int Type = notifType==0?r.nextInt(max):notifType;

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                while (true) 
               {
                  try 
                  {
                      Thread.sleep(1000); 
                  }
                  catch (Exception e) 
                  { 
                      e.printStackTrace(); 
                  }
                  Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() 
                  {
                     public void run() 
                     {
                          //IT'S NEVER ENTER HERE!!!
                          NotifierDialog.notify(Title, Text, NotificationType.values()[Type]);
                          while (!NotifierDialog._shell.isDisposed()) 
                          {
                              if (!Display.getDefault().readAndDispatch()) Display.getDefault().sleep();
                          }
                          Display.getDefault().dispose();
                     }
                     });
               }
            }
         }).start();
 }
```

My problem is that it never enters the `run()` function.

It's stuck on `Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable()...` and that's all.
I know `Display.syncExec` should wait until its can run but I don't know how to make it ready...

Help?

Comment: Is this SWT? Eclipse RCP?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm using Eclipse with SWT. how can I know what is my SWT  version? I know this `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display`

Comment: Which run() are you referring to?

Comment: @m0skit0 this: `public void run() 
                     {
                          //IT'S NEVER ENTER HERE!!!
                          NotifierDialog.notify(Title, Text, NotificationType.values()[Type]);
                          while (!NotifierDialog._shell.isDisposed()) 
                          {
                              if (!Display.getDefault().readAndDispatch()) Display.getDefault().sleep();
                          }
                          Display.getDefault().dispose();
                     }`

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You should call it new Thread( Display.getDefault,...))

Comment: I want to be able to run this                           `NotifierDialog.notify(Title, Text, NotificationType.values()[Type]);` this use a shell that's use the display. but the Display thread never enter the inner `run()` function...

Comment: Well, it's very hard to analyze the problem here without a runnable snippet. Your code is very confusing, I guess you want to have a modal dialog or somthing similar, why are you using dispatch, sleep methods? - In general this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are adding the `Runnable` to the wrong display thread. Use the `current` thread, not the `default`. Replace everywhere.

> getCurrent()
>
> Returns the display which the currently running thread is the
>   user-interface thread for, or null if the currently running thread is
>   not a user-interface thread for any display.

```
Display.getCurrent().syncExec(new Runnable() {
});
```

Comment: getCurrent() fixed the issue! THANKS!